# bash variable substitution with grep default behavior

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I am trying to read user name and password from file and store each in a variable the problem is I get the line containing the data with grep and store it in a variable using variable substitution but grep always print the output to the screen,
Here is the code:

```
user_line=$(grep "$l_user_name" "user_data")
```

how can I store the output in user_line without printing it to the screen

Comment: What is `grep` saying? The command looks fine if `user_data` is a file and `$l_user_name` a defined var.

Comment: What you have there should do what you want.

Comment: @fedorqui you are right I'm searching for $l_user_name in user_data

Comment: @mbratch the problem is grep is printing the output to the screen

Comment: It seems that `grep` is printing the `STDERR` to the screen, not the _output_.

Comment: @devnull grep prints the right output and I want suppress that

Comment: please cut and paste from your shell session showing the issue

Answer (score 0):

I believe quoting is highly recommended here:

```
user_line=$(grep "$l_user_name" "user_data")
```

Without quoting if `$l` contains spaces then grep will write some error on stderr.

Comment: the command working fine all I want is to store the output of grep in user_line without grep printing it to the screen and thanks for the tip

Comment: Are you sure you're using BASH? Try `user_line=\`grep "$l_user_name" "user_data")\``

Comment: OK Is it possible for you to reproduce this problem on ideone.com editor using BASH flavor?

Comment: how can I upload user_data file to ideone.com?

Comment: No not the file, you can take some strings out from file and run grep using heredoc syntax. OR post small input file snippet in the question  then I will create a indeone.com sample